# Group by reduced field depending on variable in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection for messages:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d5632001bae07a6e6b3"),
    "sender_id" : 8,
    "receiver_id" : 2,
    "content" : "fdgfd",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023062899.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d5c32001bae07a6e6b4"),
    "sender_id" : 2,
    "receiver_id" : 8,
    "content" : "fasfa",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023068443.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d8032001bae07a6e6b5"),
    "sender_id" : 2,
    "receiver_id" : 8,
    "content" : "dfdsfds",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023104363.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d8032001bae07a6e6b6"),
    "sender_id" : 2,
    "receiver_id" : 8,
    "content" : "fdsf",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023104825.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d8132001bae07a6e6b7"),
    "sender_id" : 2,
    "receiver_id" : 8,
    "content" : "sfsdfs",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023105436.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d8132001bae07a6e6b8"),
    "sender_id" : 2,
    "receiver_id" : 8,
    "content" : "f",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023105963.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214d8432001bae07a6e6b9"),
    "sender_id" : 2,
    "receiver_id" : 8,
    "content" : "qwqwqwq",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023108202.0000000000000000
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56214db032001bae07a6e6ba"),
    "sender_id" : 9902,
    "receiver_id" : 2,
    "content" : "fsafa",
    "state" : 1,
    "timestamp" : 1445023152297.0000000000000000
}
```

I'm trying to get all unique users ids that had been messaging with user 2, along with the last content message. So the result should be:

```
[ { user: 8, lastContent: "qwqwqwq" }, { user: 9902, lastContent: "fsafa" } ]
```

By now, I have the following code:

```
db.getCollection('messenger').group({
keyf: function(doc) {
    return { user: doc.user };
},
cond: {
    $or : [
        { sender_id : 2 },
        { receiver_id : 2 }
    ]
},
reduce: function( curr, result ) {
    result.user = (curr.sender_id == 2 ? curr.receiver_id : curr.sender_id);
    result.content = curr.content;
 },
 initial: { } })
```

But I only get the last id. The result:

```
{
"0" : {
    "user" : 9902.0000000000000000,
    "content" : "fsafa"
} }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. You need to reduce the size of documents in the pipeline using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator which filter out all documents where the `receiver_id` is not equal to `2`. After that you need to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your document by `timestamp` in descending order this will help us get the `content`  of last message sent. Now comes the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you group your documents and use the [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) operator which returns array of distinct `sender_id` and distinct `receiver_id` and the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last) operator to get the last message content. Now to get the `user_ids` we need union of distinct `sender_id` and `receiver_id` which we can get after [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)ion using the [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) operator.

```js
db.messenger.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [ 
            { "sender_id": 2 }, 
            { "receiver_id": 2 } 
        ] 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },  
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "receiver_id": { 
            "$addToSet": { "$receiver_id" }
        },
        "sender_id": { 
            "$addToSet": { "$sender_id" }
        }, 
        "lastContent": { "$last": "$content" } 
    }},
    { "$project": { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "lastContent": 1, 
        "user_ids": { 
            "$setUnion": [ 
                "$sender_id", 
                "$receiver_id" 
            ] 
        }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "lastContent" : "fsafa", "user_ids" : [ 9902, 2, 8 ] }
```

Now if what you want is distinct user alongside their last content message with user `2` then here it is:

```js
db.messenger.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [ 
            { "sender_id": 2 }, 
            { "receiver_id": 2 } 
        ] 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },  
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "sender": "$sender_id", 
            "receiver": "$receiver_id"
        }, 
        "lastContent": { 
            "$last": "$content"
        }, 
        "timestamp": { "$last": "$timestamp" }, 
        "sender": { "$addToSet": "$sender_id" }, 
        "receiver": { "$addToSet": "$receiver_id" }
    }}, 
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0, 
        "user": { 
            "$setDifference": [ 
                { "$setUnion": [ "$sender", "$receiver" ] }, 
                [ 2 ] 
            ]
        }, 
        "lastContent": 1,  
        "timestamp": 1 
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$user" },
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$user", 
        "lastContent": { "$last": "$lastContent" }
    } }
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : 9902, "lastContent" : "fsafa" }
{ "_id" : 8, "lastContent" : "qwqwqwq" }
```